# Can't install snapd on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, snap, apparmor

snapd on my machine is not working and I tried reinstalling using `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`

I got the below error.

```
Unpacking snapd (2.38+18.04) over (2.38+18.04) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up snapd (2.38+18.04) ...
md5sum: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine: No such file or directory
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for snapd.seeded.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status snapd.seeded.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
```

I rebooted the machine and tried this but of no luck.
How can I solve this?

**Update:**

1. As per the output, I ran the commands `systemctl status snapd.service` and `journalctl -xe`. The below is their output.

```
mithilesh@linux:~$ systemctl status snapd.service
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-05-19 16:55:24 IST; 5h 43mi
  Process: 833 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 833 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple
```

```
mithilesh@linux:~$ journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Activating 
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Activating 
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Activating 
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Activating 
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Successfull
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Successfull
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Successfull
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: Could not establish a connection to Tracke
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL'
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' fa
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL'
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' fa
May 19 22:36:35 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL
May 19 22:36:35 linux dbus-daemon[2408]: [session uid=1000 pid=2408] Successfull
May 19 22:36:36 linux gnome-calendar[4156]: source_credentials_required_cb: Fail
May 19 22:36:37 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL'
May 19 22:36:37 linux nautilus[4154]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' fa
```

2. Based on the comments, the below is the output of running `snap list`, `snap version` and `snap warnings`

```
mithilesh@linux:~$ snap list
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/snaps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
mithilesh@linux:~$ snap version
snap    2.38+18.04
snapd   unavailable
series  -
mithilesh@linux:~$ snap warnings
error: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/warnings: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

3. Running `sudo apt autoclean` and `sudo apt autoremove` didn't through any errors. But for `sudo apt update`, warnings are returned for `google-chorme` application.

Comment: How does exactly it do not work? What is the output of `snap list`, `snap version`, `snap warnings` (add them into the question).

Comment: Do the commands `apt autoclean`, `apt autoremove` and `apt update` give any error messages? Run each command one by one by preceding with `sudo `.

Comment: Your output pointed you to `systemctl status snapd.service` and of `journalctl -xe`. Please edit your question to include the complete output of both.

Comment: Updated the question. Please take a look @N0rbert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output is a bit strange.

I can recommend to start from scratch by purging `snapd` package and reinstalling it back with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd
sudo apt-get install snapd
```